# Enviar datos SIN RECARGAR el formulario con php y ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

espero que se encuentren bien

Tengo un proyecto en donde necesito enviar datos de un formulario sin que se recargue la pagina, quiero conservar los datos en caso de que exista algún error, eh visto que esto se puede realizar con ajax pero como casi no lo uso, soy bastante inexperto, encontré que se puede enviando los datos a una clase php  pero se me complica ya que dentro de la clase php tengo varios metodos que reciben datos de otros formularios

espero y me puedan ayudar, GRACIAS!!

Comment: Veo que usas la etiqueta AJAX, esa es la respuesta.

Comment: Publica lo que tienes, así podríamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

aquí un ejemplo usando jquery:

cuando de click en el boton Mostrar me captura por ejemplo el id del dato que quiero mostrar.

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
       <button class="btn btn-warning modalMostrarDT" iddatos="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalMostrar"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
    </div>
</td>
```

atravez de FormData puedo enviar varios valores al archivo php, que los recibe, damos un nombre a ese dato en este caso idDT y seguido enviamos la variable idDatos ("idDT", idDatos).

```
$(document).on("click",".botonMostrar", function(){
        /**capturamos un valor de un input por ejemplo que tiene id="iddatos"*/
        var idDatos = $('#iddatos').val();;
    
        /*atravez de FormData recogemos los datos existentes le asignamos un nombre y le pasamos la variable*/
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("idDT", idDatos);
             /*abrimo ajax donde vamos a enviar a envar datos sin recargar pagina*/
        $.ajax({
             /*url ponemos la dirrecion (ruta) de nuestro archivo ajax.php en ese caso esta dentro de una carpeta nombre ajax*/
             /*el metodo de envio es POST*/
             /*data type es la forma en que los archivos seran devueltos despues de hacer algo en php*/
            url:"ajax/archivosinrecargarpagina.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
    
            success: function(respuesta){
    
                console.log(respuesta);
    
                /*** AQUI VA LO QUE QUIERES HACER CON TU RESPUESTA */
    
            }
    
        });
    
    })
```

AQUI ARCHIVO PHP: archivosinrecargarpagina.ajax.php

```
    <?php
            
                class AjaxPHP{
                    /********************************************
                    ARCHIVO PHP DONDE VIENEN LOS DATOS ENVIADOS DESDE EL ARCHIVO JS CON METODO AJAX
                    *********************************************/
                    public $iddt;
        
                    public function ajaxConsulta(){
            
                        $valor = $this->iddt;
            
                        /*hacemos lo que queremos con ese valor por ejemplo la consulta a la bd*/
            
                        $respuesta = /*conexion, select*/;
            
                        /*ese resutado lo devolvemos a el archivo js donde estan solicitando la respuesta*/
                        echo json_encode($respuesta);
                    }
            
                }
            /*aqui estamos recibiendo la variable POST idDT
        preguntamos si existe, instanciamos la clase ajaxPHP pasamos el valor recibido y ejecutamos el metodo consulta*/
                if (isset($_POST["idDT"])) {

                    $editaram = new AjaxPHP();
                    $editaram -> iddt= $_POST["idDT"];
                    $editaram -> ajaxConsulta();


                  /*si quieres saber con exactitud si la variable esta llegando a este archivo ajax puede hacer sin comentarlo echo json_encode($_POST["idDT"]); eso te devolvera el mismo valor ala pagina de javascript donde se esta solicitando la repuesta ajax  eso si tienes que comentar las lineas 
                    $editaram = new AjaxPHP();
                    $editaram -> iddt= $_POST["idDT"];
                    $editaram -> ajaxConsulta(); 
                    y como dije anteriormente solo dejas echo json_encode($_POST["idDT"]);*/
                }
        
        <?
```